# Best way to find out if a DLL is present in the system

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

I am currently using LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary functions to check if a dll(mfplat.dll) is present in the system where my application is running. My requirement is only to check if the dll is present in the system and i do not need to invoke any of the functions from the dll. Is there a faster way to check the same?

Comment: Is speed really important here?

Comment: Define "present on your system". Anywhere on the system, or available to dll search? Also why do you feel the need to check? Why not deal with load failure when it happens. You have to do that anyway. Why write extra code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`LoadLibraryEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx) and set the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` bit for the `dwFlags` argument.

From MSDN:

> If this value is used, the system maps the file into the calling
>   process's virtual address space as if it were a data file. Nothing is
>   done to execute or prepare to execute the mapped file.

So this should give a significant speedup compared to plain `LoadLibrary()`.

Comment: Beyond speedup, this avoids executing code in the dll, probably a more important consideration